# How to connect to remote sql server from SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, linked-server

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have to access our company portal database which is maintained by a third party.

They had given me login details. Please explain how to connect to their database. I can't post the link here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the [linked servers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) feature for this.

It is used to:

> Configure a linked server to enable the SQL Server Database Engine to execute commands against OLE DB data sources outside of the instance of SQL Server.

Comment: i am having user name, pass word, database name and database host address. none of these are asking in linked server configuration. please give suggestion what should i do

Comment: @user1594415 - The provider string parameter is the connection string that will contains the credentials. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx